# When does a system of linear equations have no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I've just finished the first lecture of MIT 18.06 *Linear Algebra with Gilbert Strang*. The professor briefly discusses how one can find out whether $A x = b$ as a solution.

I don't understand this example that he gave:

> Imagine that there are $9$ components in a $9$-dimensional space and the eighth component is the same as the ninth component; then you will not be able to find a solution.

Comment: The wording is a little vague, but I imagine what he's getting at is this: If a matrix mapped two different vectors ('eighth and ninth components') to the same place, there'd be no way to 'undo' this since you'd have no idea where it came from. It's like how you can't uniquely solve $x^2=1$ since $-1$ and $1$ both square to the same thing.

Comment: In two dimensions, the system $\,x+y=0,\; x+y=1\,$ has no solutions, and the system $\,x+y = 1,$ $\; 2x+2y=2\,$ has infinitely many.

Comment: Think geometrically: what is a linear equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and what is a solution to a system of such equations? Can you imagine a situation in which a solution would then not exist? If so, how would this translate into algebra? The comments above mine basically explain this.

Comment: A system of linear equations has no solution iff its augmented matrix has a greater rank than its coefficient matrix. (And, notice from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283775/21813) that an inconsistent system of $q$ linear equations and $n$ variables can have its equations dependent or independent, and can be such that $q<n$ or $q=n$ or $q>n$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about every equation in the system as describing an affine subspace of the domain. If a solution exists, that vector must satisfy all the equations simultaneously, therefore it must lie in the intersection of the subspaces described by the equations in the system.
Now it's easy to construct example where:

- A unique solution exists, for example take two lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ instersecting in exactly one point:
  $$\ell_1 = \{x-y=0\}, \quad \ell_2 =\{x+y =1\},$$
  then the linear system
  $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
  has a unique solution (the intersection of the lines).
- A solution doesn't exists: take two parallel line, there is no intersection.
- Infinite solution exists: take $\ell_1 = \ell_2$.

In general the information you need is encoded in the ranks of the matrices $A$ and $(A|b)$.